# Update UI thread in winforms application reliably

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I have a long running machine learning program that I run in the background ***in parallel using all cores*** in a winforms application.  Periodically I update the UI to report on progress.

The machine seems to choose fairly random times to execute the message pump on the UI thread.  Sometimes I get no updates for several minutes, sometimes I get a message every time I send one.

I've tried every which way to make this reliable including standard invoking from the background thread, using progress reporting from a backgroundworker, using a timer on the UI thread to collect information and display it, reducing the maximum number of threads that can run in parallel, messing with thread priorities etc.  The only way I've found to reliably get an update is to add a console to the winforms program and output progress to the console.  For some reason, that is 100% reliable, but it is a real hack and looks messy.

Does anyone know of a way to  force the ui thread to be updated reliably?

As requested:  Here is the most basic code that replicates the error.  Create a form with a label called label1. The code is an attempt to update the label every millionth iteration.

```
Module testmodule
delegate sub invokedelegate(txt as string)

Sub long_running_process()
    Dim x(100000000) As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim syncobject As New Object

    form1.Label1.Text = "started"

    Parallel.ForEach(x, Sub(z)

                            '*** This just put in to make the processors do some work.
                            Dim p As New Random
                            Dim m As Double = p.NextDouble
                            Dim zzz As Double = Math.Cosh(m) + Math.Cos(m)

                            '*** This is the basic updating method.
                            SyncLock syncobject
                                cnt += 1

                                '*** Update every millionth iteration
                                If cnt Mod 1000000 < 1 Then

                                    '**** This is how it is marshalled to the UI thead.
                                    If Form1.InvokeRequired Then
                                        Form1.BeginInvoke(New invokedelegate(AddressOf invokemethod), {cnt})
                                    Else
                                        Form1.Label1.Text = cnt
                                    End If

                                End If
                            End SyncLock
                        End Sub)

    Form1.Label1.Text = "Finished"
End Sub
Sub invokemethod(txt As String)
    form1.Label1.Text = txt
End Sub
end module
```

Comment: The UI thread doesn't *choose* to run the message pump now and then - that's all it does, over and over, all day, every day.  If you're not getting messages it's because you either are not sending them *or* the UI thread is too busy to process them in a timely manner.  If you are sure that you are sending messages, use a profiler to time how long your UI thread needs to execute the handler attached to each message.  If it's longer than the period between update messages then you will accumulate a message backlog and things will stop working. A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Another possibility could be resource contention - if your threads are allocating memory frequently they may be monopolizing the memory manager and if your UI handler also needs to allocate memory, it may be stuck waiting for the threads to give it a turn... again, without any code to see what you are actually doing it is very difficult to offer specific advice.

Comment: Are you using `BeginInvoke` to post your message back to the UI thread message pump? If you do that, I don't think you should see any issues like this. If you post the code you use to marshal the UI updates, it would be helpful for us to identify the issue.

Comment: I've added a minimal complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Parallel.ForEach` insists on running the all tasks on the UI thread. One way I got this changed was by calling the `long_running_process` from a `BackgroundWorker.DoWork`, like so:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        testmodule.long_running_process(Label1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Notice that I had to provide the `Label1` as a parameter because  otherwise the InvokeRequired always returned false.

The changed `long_running_process` looks like this:

```
Sub long_running_process(lbl As Label)
    Dim x(100000000) As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim syncobject As New Object

    If lbl.InvokeRequired Then
        lbl.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                              lbl.Text = "started"
                                          End Sub), Nothing)
    End If


    Parallel.ForEach(x, Sub(z)

                            '*** This just put in to make the processors do some work.
                            Dim p As New Random
                            Dim m As Double = p.NextDouble
                            Dim zzz As Double = Math.Cosh(m) + Math.Cos(m)

                            '*** This is the basic updating method.
                            SyncLock syncobject
                                cnt += 1

                                '*** Update every millionth iteration
                                If cnt Mod 1000000 < 1 Then

                                    '**** This is how it is marshalled to the UI thead.
                                    If lbl.InvokeRequired Then
                                        lbl.BeginInvoke(New invokedelegate(AddressOf invokemethod), {cnt.ToString()})
                                    Else
                                        lbl.Text = cnt
                                    End If

                                End If
                            End SyncLock
                        End Sub)

    If lbl.InvokeRequired Then
        lbl.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                              lbl.Text = "Finished"
                                          End Sub), Nothing)
    End If

End Sub
Sub invokemethod(txt As String)
    Form1.Label1.Text = txt
End Sub
```

The counter updates smoothly with these changes.

Comment: Many thanks.  I have tried running it in as a background process - but not in the example code. and it hasn't worked.  What intrigues me is why the invokerequired always returns false unless you pass the label as a parameter.  The passing of the label  is almost definitely the solution to my problem.  But do you know why it works?

Comment: @GavinPotter the VB.NET project and compiler adds magic so you can reach Form1 as a static reference with a factory to create the form if it doesn't exist yet. However the backing collection is marked as `[ThreadStatic]` which means each thread has its own set of active Forms. This means that `Form1` on the UI-thread is a different `Form1` on the background thread. When both caller and form are on the same thread InvokeRequired returns false.

Comment: Many thanks - I didn't realise that and that accounts for a number of other issues that I've been having.

Comment: VB.NET and/or the project default generated helper classes hide complexity which can be useful in simple scenario's. It makes it harder to diagnose potential bugs. I used ILSpy to peek inside the generated stuff to workout what was going on.